# One structure section for multiple menu's (navigations)

Tags: templating, structure, navigation

I want to use one structure section for multiple menu's (navigations). So I want all pages under topmenu in the topmenu (header) and I want all pages in the bottommenu in a menu in the footer. How can I accomplish this most easily in my twig file?
[image: example of my structure lay-out]

Comment: Not really a direct answer to your question, but for specialized menus I prefer using this plugin: https://github.com/am-impact/amnav

Comment: Hi Peirix, I know that plugin, but wanted to solve it native with Craft. I didn't want my users to do things on two places (first add content and then add it to a menu-item). Thanks for suggesting though! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something i've used, it should work for you, the only downside to it is there being a hardcoded `id`.

```
{% set nav = craft.entries.section('yourStructureSection') %}

{% set headerItems = nav.descendantOf(TopMenuId) %}

{% set footerItems = nav.descendantOf(BottomMenuId) %}
```

So you would just replace `TopMenuId` with the entry `id` of `Topmenu` and `BottomMenuId` with the entry id of `Bottommenu`

Then you will be able to loop through each nav :)

**Edit**

```
<nav>
 {% nav entry in craft.entries.section('contentPages').descendantOf(13) %} 
    <li> <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }} </a>
        {% ifchildren %}
            <ul> {% children %} </ul> 
        {% endifchildren %}
    </li> 
 {% endnav %}
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks Alec, good suggestion. I tried this, but didn't work completely. What am i doing wrong? `{% set nav = craft.entries.section('contentPages') %}
   {% set headerItems = nav.descendantOf('topmenu') %}
   <nav>
       <ul>
          {% nav page in headerItems %}
              <li>
                  <a href="{{ page.singleEntrySelector.first().url | default }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
              </li>
             </ul>
            </nav>`

Comment: It looks like where you have `topmenu`, this needs to be the numerical `ID` of the entry

Comment: I've updated my answer, it now has code based on your comment above, just a bit of refactoring. I can't see anything wrong with this snippet though? Are you missing an `{% endblock %}` or some other closing tag?

Comment: Awesome, no worries :)